# Trying to edit single elements in dynamic jagged array edits several instead

Tags: arrays, powershell, powershell-4.0

I am trying to make a dynamically sized jagged array to represent a game grid for a very simple console game.

```
# Determine the size of the board. Enforce the size so as to not make it too large. 
$boardSize = 5

# Game board characters
[char]$bushCharacter = "#"

# Initialize Game board object
$gameBoard = ,(@($bushCharacter) * $boardSize) * $boardSize
```

Idea being that if I was to print it out on the screen. I would get something like this which I do.

```
0..($boardSize - 1) | ForEach-Object{$gameBoard[$_] -join ""}

#####
#####
#####
#####
#####
```

All is well until I try to make a change to an individual item: `$gameBoard[0][1] = "F"`. My expected result from reprinting the grid is

```
#F###
#####
#####
#####
#####
```

My actual output is:

```
#F###
#F###
#F###
#F###
#F###
```

This tells me that the array I made has all rows referencing each other. Why would this code not create separate unique arrays? What change could I make to make it work. I know other approaches would work like a index loop with `+=` but I thought this approach was a better practice.

Comment: I know I am close to figuring this one out for myself but this _seemed_ like a good question.

Comment: The outer array values all reference the same inner array (compare `$gameBoard[0].GetHashCode()` and `$gameBoard[1].GetHashCode()`)

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen Assumed as much. Wouldn't have figured multiplying it would do that but no matter. Do you know what I would do to change that or should I just be doing a different creation method?

Comment: Pretty sure you need to use a different method, see my answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the documentation for the multiplication operator (`*`), you'll find that (from [`about_Arithmetic_Operators`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh848303.aspx)):

```
    *         Multiplies integers; copies strings     6*2
              and arrays the specified number of      "w" * 3
              times.
```

Notice the word ***copies***.

Now take a look at the MSDN documentation for the .NET [`Array.Copy()` method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k4yx47a1(v=vs.110).aspx), under the **Remarks** section:

> If *sourceArray* and *destinationArray* are both reference-type arrays or are both arrays of type Object, **a shallow copy is performed**. A shallow copy of an Array is a new Array containing references to the same elements as the original Array. The elements themselves or anything referenced by the elements are not copied. In contrast, a deep copy of an Array copies the elements and everything directly or indirectly referenced by the elements.

It's fair to assume that the array multiplication operator *always* produces the same kind of array - ie. either a reference-type array or an Object array (whatever that is) - and this is basically what you see the effects of.

I'd do:

```
$gameBoard = 1..$boardSize |ForEach-Object { ,@(@($bushCharacter) * $boardSize) }
```

Answer (score 2):

`Array` is a [reference type](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t63sy5hs.aspx) and because of that you are only multiplying (copying) the reference/pointer and not the content itself.

Workaround: Create a loop to generate unique arrays.

```
$gameBoard = 0..($boardSize - 1) | ForEach-Object{ ,(@($bushCharacter) * $boardSize) }
```

You can verify (without documentation) that an object is a reference type by using:

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName "Microsoft.VisualBasic"
[Microsoft.VisualBasic.Information]::IsReference($gameBoard[0])
True

#or as mentioned by Mathias
-not $gameBoard[0].GetType().IsValueType
True
```

Comment: You can also check whether a runtime type is a reference type without the `Microsoft.VisualBasic` assembly: `-not $gameBoard[0].GetType().IsValueType`

Comment: Nice. Thought I had seen something simpler before :-)